# I can not play video WebView

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview

please! somebody tell me! how to play video in WebView???

```
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http://m.ochepyatki.ru/video.php?vkey=be38112&f=11395221100");
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: are you playing in emulator ?

Comment: I'm testing on telefone.oshibok no, simply can not be played. white screen and all. try different links

Comment: what type of video is this flv,mp4 or swf

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidManifest.xml add

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Ex:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >

<activity>...</activity>
</application>
```